# How to handle a var / const in the EmberJS controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a game controller, there is a `setPause` method and there is `const statusPause = true / false`, how can I access const `statusPause` from other files, `services`, etc. To perform some checks depending on the state of the game? If you do this in any file, `undefined` is returned instead of `bool`.

```
let game = require('../controllers/game');
console.log(game.setPause.statusPause);
```

Comment: Please share the code of the `setPause` method.

Comment: Also please clarify what do you mean by `services, etc`... What kind of services?

Answer (score 1):

You firstly need to make sure that the service that the code ('setPause' method) belongs to is exported properly.

```
import Service from '@ember/service';
export default Service.extend({
   setPause(){
        //code
   }
});
```

and then in the other service you can import (in the case of the service inject).
I will name the above service to nameOfTheOtherService

```
import Service from '@ember/service';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Service.extend({
   nameOfTheOtherService : service(),
   let myBoolVariable = this.get('nameOfTheOtherService').setPause();
});
```

Hopefully this is what you need. 
Let me know or share code if you need some more help